# How to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}, i)$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

That is, find a minimal polynomial that splits over this field.  So, is it enough to do this?:

$x = \sqrt[6]{2} = 0$, therefore $x^6 = 2$ and thus $x^6-2$ is a factor.

$x = i$, therefore $x^2 = -1$ and thus $x^2+1$ is a factor.

Then multiply them together and get the minimal polynomial?  What's wrong with this approach?  I saw one example where we took the sum of the adjoined roots and used that to find the minimal polynomial.

Comment: what's wrong with this approach?  you're looking for a minimal polynomial, and minimal polynomials are irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[6]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is obviously the irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^6-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Similarly, the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $g(x)=x^2+1$. If $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}, i)$ were a splitting field, then it would be the smallest field such that $f(x)$ splits into the product of linear factors. Given that $f(x) = (x-\sqrt[6]{2})(x-\omega \sqrt[6]{2})(x-\omega^2 \sqrt[6]{2})(x-\omega^3\sqrt[6]{2})(x-\omega^4\sqrt[6]{2})(x-\omega^5\sqrt[6]{2})$, where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/6}$, if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2},i)$ were the splitting field, it would contain all of these roots.

Think about whether $\mathbb{Q}(\omega) = \mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^6-2$ has another 5 roots. The Field contains all the roots ?

Comment: I can't tell if this is a legitimate question or if you're guiding the OP to a flaw in their reasoning.

Comment: well they would be in the basis, right?

Comment: @AgtissaAgtissan-Samsikkc Why would they be in the basis? For example, the field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root6\of2)$ contains a root of the irreducible polynomial $p(x)=x^6-2$, but it is not a splitting field because it does not contain ALL the roots of $p(x)$. Simply because some of the roots are complex numbers and $K$ is a subset of the reals.